# Kentico migration to SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, kentico

I currently have a customer who has Kentico and is willing to migration to SharePoint 2013
Does any body have any experience with migrating Kentico cms to SharePoint 2013?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly experienced as a Kentico consultant, and VERY experienced in SharePoint. Here's my 2 cents, though it is likely not going to be good news:

Unfortunately for you, this is not a "migration" so much as a "port" (i.e. duplicate content from one system to the other). Kentico CMS and SharePoint 2013 really have very little in common. Kentico is a web content management system (asset management, workflow, publishing, marketing, WYSIWYG HTML editor, etc.). SharePoint is a glorified document storage system. Even if you are talking about the "full" version of SharePoint vs. the "free" version, there is very little in common with Kentico.